# Pre evaluate LLVM IR

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

Let's suppose we have expressions like:

```
  %rem = srem i32 %i.0, 10
  %mul = mul nsw i32 %rem, 2
```

- %i.0 is a llvm::PHINode which I can get the bounds.

The question is: Is there a way to get the value of %mul during compile time? I'm writing a llvm Pass and I need to evaluate some expressions which use %i.0. I'm searching for a function, class or something else which I will give a value to %i.0 and it will evaluate the expression and return the result.

Answer (score 2):

You could clone the code (the containing function or the entire module, depending on how much context you need), then replace `%i.0` with a constant value, run the constant propagation pass on the code, and finally check whether `%mul` is assigned to a constant value and if so, extract it.

It's not elegant, but I think it would work. Just pay attention to:

1. Make sure `%mul` is not elided out - for example, return it from the function, or store its value to memory, or something.
2. Be aware constant propagation assumes some things about the code, in particular that it already passed through mem2reg.